# Emulator Load error - Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to android. I am trying to develop android helloworld application as given in all tutorials.

Using Configuration: Android 3.1 for configuration.
When i try to run in eclipse i get error:

```
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] -----------------------------
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] Performing com.hello.HelloWorldActivity activity launch
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: Files\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-arm.exe.
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-10 13:39:19 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced with SDK tools r12. You can do either of two things:

- Install your SDK into your C:\ root directory instead of C:\Program Files
- In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> Android. If you placed your SDK in C:\Program Files, change that to C:\PROGRA~1. If you placed it in C:\Program Files (x86), change it to C:\PROGRA~2. Eclipse is going to complain, so in your command line terminal, run `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`. If you haven't set up your PATH variable yet, then, in the command prompt, navigate to (path to sdk)\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools, and run those two commands from there.

Comment: thnx for the help. Its working now But the size of emulator gets out of the screen. How to manage the size?

Comment: Edit your emulator to use a lower resolution/density like HVGA or QVGA. Personally, I use HVGA because QVGA is way too small, and HVGA is the largest size that can fit on my 1366x768 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your android sdk might not be configured correctly.
Did you try to run the emulator from command line?
[http://www.ceveni.com/2009/12/run-android-emulator-from-command-line.html][1]