# Android Emulator unable to run

Tags: android, emulation

Hi I am trying to run my application on android Emulator . . yesterday it was working fine and right now its working fine on device . . but when I select Emulator it gives me error as in attached image . .Anyone can guide what's the reason . .?[image]

Comment: Please check below link may be useful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730013/android-project-run-error

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639994/emulator-load-error-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are changing the path of the android sdk folder.The path can't contain spaces.Like if you keep it in **Program Files/android-sdk-windows** it will create problem because **Program Files** has a space on the path

Answer (score 1):

```
android-sdk-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>emulator -avd  new -scale 0.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: goto the AVD Manager and create new Emulator the name should not have any special characters. Then launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the old virtual device, deleting the temporary folder (**c:\documents and settings\user.android\avd**) and creating a new one should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

appear this error because you are putting android sdk in path which has some space.**Ex: Program files**.Please move to other path which has no space.